# Div loses all styling when wrapped in <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a project where I want to change some circle elements into hyperlinks by wrapping them in an `<a href>`.  The problem is, I lose the styling that I had previously applied after I wrap the html div in the `<a>` tag. I am having trouble finding a solution after adding the `<a>` tag in the css.

Here is a Codepen I have created of a draft project. Try wrapping a .circle div in an `<a>` tag:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/koriwade/pen/kkgEVo?editors=1100)

In case CodePen is down

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper .first {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 1222px;
}
.wrapper .first .circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #FF9E9D;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FF9E9D;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <div class="circle">
      <h5>MD</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using your CodePen I don't see any loss, even the underline cited by the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you want the entire div to be a link why not give the a tag a class of that style. For example

```html
<a class="first" href="your link"></a>
```

Note that ".first" can be any of the classes you want your link to be or you want your user to click on to go to that link

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solution worked great. I know know what I was doing wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine while i do it in that code pen

```
<a href="#"><div class="circle"><h5>MD</h5></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="circle"><h5>MD</h5></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="circle"><h5>MD</h5></div></a>    
    <a href="#"><div class="circle"><h5>MD</h5></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="circle"><h5>MD</h5></div></a>
```

this is what i done

or

```
<div class="circle"><a href="#"><h5>MD</h5></a></div>
```

is also looks fine

Comment: Thanks for you help. Your solution is working for me.

Comment: pleasure is always mine. :)